# Problem in saving string values in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I have a screen in my BlackBerry app which shows a title at the top.  The title comes from an xml page fetched over the network, that also specifies some list field text values. Clicking those list field items takes the user to the next screen, and clicking back/escape takes the user to the original list field screen.

The problem is the title now shows "null". How can I preserve the value of the title when I transit from one screen to another?

Answer (score 0):

When user presses escape/back button then the active screen gets popped and the previous screen pushed in the stack becomes the active screen.

I believe that the variable that displays the title losts its data when u clicked pushscreen.

Please check using the method onExposed() that value persists or there is some other issue.

BTW samples for persistence:

http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17952/Storing_objects_persistently_1219782_11.jsp

http://www.blackberryprogramming.com/tutorials/object-persistence/

http://www.blackberrytutor.info/tutorials/37-general/49-persistent-storage

Answer (score 0):

You need to get Ur data for setTile persistantly.Follow the link below.

http://www.blackberryprogramming.com/tutorials/object-persistence/